# why the image doesn't open?

Tags: image, qml, qtquick2

I have use a `Q_PROPERTY` to set `source` of an `Image` in my qml file. the qml file is in a resource but the source path is out of resource so I set the prepend equal to `file://`. when it tries to open the Image, this error occurs but the path is true:

> qrc:/MainWindow.qml:34:9: QML Image: Cannot open: file:///home/me/Pictures/05.Jun.2017_00:23:57:149.jpg
>   how can I fix it?

Comment: show your code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show code with your resource file structure **OR** you can debug it first by using following code. First try to add it manually in your QML if its working then you can check for accessing it from Q_Property. Don't use "file://"

```
Image {
    anchors.fill: parent
    source: "qrc:/Images/Images/hello.png"
}
```